# Streaming of data not working in React client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, stream, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a React application the expects a response stream. To simplify the scenario, let's say I have an endpoint that returns a number every second. I am using Flask for this purpose:

```py
def stream():
    def generate():
        import math, time
        for i in range(10):
            yield f'{i}\n'
            time.sleep(1)

    return generate(), {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
```

In my React component, a button click will trigger the following function:

```js
const readStream = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.seenBytes = 0;
  xhr.open('GET', '/stream', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 3){
      const data = xhr.response.substr(xhr.seenBytes)
      console.log(data)
      setNumber(data)  // set state value that will be displayed elsewhere
      xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

For some reason, the React code fails to get the chunks one at a time and it just dumps the data all at once. I've verified that using the same ajax request in vanilla JS works. I've tried different approach as well including using `fetch` and `axios` but none worked so far.

Though I am using `GET` here, my actual use case requires `POST` and I have to get my data from that response.

Is there anything I am missing out?

Answer (score -3):

It seems that you are facing an issue with receiving streaming data in your React application using XMLHttpRequest. The problem you described suggests that the data is not being received in chunks but **rather all at once**.

One possible reason for this behavior is that XMLHttpRequest's onreadystatechange event might not be firing during the streaming process. Instead, it waits until the response is complete before triggering. To overcome this issue, you can modify your code to use the xhr.onprogress event instead, which is specifically designed for tracking data as it is being received.

Here's an updated version of your code using the onprogress event:

```
const readStream = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/stream', true);
  xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
    const data = xhr.response.substr(xhr.seenBytes);
    console.log(data);
    setNumber(data); // set state value that will be displayed elsewhere
    xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length;
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

By replacing **onreadystatechange** with **onprogress**, you should be able to receive the streaming data in chunks as expected.

Regarding your mention of using POST in your actual use case, the same approach can be applied. You will need to modify both the server-side code and the client-side code accordingly.

On the server side (Flask), you would change the endpoint to accept POST requests:

```
@app.route('/stream', methods=['POST'])
def stream():
    # Your streaming logic here
```

On the client side (React), you would update the xhr.open method to specify the POST request:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/stream', true);
```

With these modifications, you should be able to receive streaming data using XMLHttpRequest with both GET and POST requests.

**Note:** Consider using more modern approaches like the **Fetch API** or **Axios** for making HTTP requests in React, as they provide simpler and more flexible options for handling streaming data.

**Update:**

```
const readStream = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/stream', true);
  xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
    const data = xhr.response.substr(xhr.seenBytes);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNumber(prevNumber => prevNumber + data); // concatenate the received chunk to the previous state value
    }, 0);
    xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length;
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

In this updated code, the setTimeout function is used with a delay of 0 milliseconds. Although it seems counterintuitive, this approach defers the state update to the next tick of the event loop, allowing React to render and update the DOM after each chunk is received.

By using setTimeout in this way, you should be able to achieve the desired streaming behavior within your React application.

Comment: I did try using `onprogress` as well. From what I've tried, everything works if I execute the streaming code outside of a React context, i.e. in vanilla JS. But when I place the code inside React, whether using `xhr`, `fetch`, or `axios` it does not stream but instead waits for all the chunks to be loaded before they can be displayed.

Comment: Right! React relies on a concept called Virtual DOM diffing, which optimizes rendering by batching updates. This batching can cause delays in updating the DOM, resulting in the behavior you described where all the chunks are loaded before being displayed.

To work around this issue, you can use the setTimeout function to schedule the update of React state after each chunk is received. By doing so, you allow React to process each chunk independently instead of waiting for the entire response to be received.

I will edit my answer with setTimeout function.

Comment: I've tried the code and it still has no effect. I am wondering if what I am doing is possible in React after all, it seems it still waits for the progress loop to finish

Comment: OK, it seems that setting the `Cache-control` header in the server to `no-transform` finally allows me to load the chunks one at a time.

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with this answer, I would encourage you to delete it. **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as it may contain fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. [Posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), and the moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.